# Show rows that have values occur a certain number of times

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to show rows in which one field  occurs a certain number of times. Assuming the following table: `Campaign`

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+  
| account_id | campaign_id | account_name | account_users |  
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|         85 |          21 | A            |            36 |  
|         45 |          69 | B            |            82 |  
|         78 |          78 | C            |            28 |  
|         69 |          65 | D            |            25 |  
|         85 |          87 | E            |            96 |  
|         78 |          12 | F            |            63 |  
|         78 |          78 | G            |            96 |  
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

And the table `Account`

```
+------------+--------------+
| account_id | account_code |
+------------+--------------+
|         85 | AAA          |
|         45 | ABC          |
|         78 | RTY          |
|         69 | WER          |
|         85 | AAA          |
|         78 | RTY          |
|         78 | RTY          |
+------------+--------------+
```

I need to show all `Campaign` table columns with (`join`) `account_code` from the table `account` for only those accounts that have `account_id` occurs two or more times at the table `campaign`. Therefore, the result should be:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| account_id | campaign_id | account_name | account_users | account_code |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|         85 |          21 | A            |            36 | AAA          |
|         78 |          78 | C            |            28 | RTY          |
|         85 |          87 | E            |            96 | AAA          |
|         78 |          12 | F            |            63 | RTY          |
|         78 |          78 | G            |            96 | RTY          |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I tried to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause but it seems not working:

```
SELECT c.account_id ,c.campaign_id ,c.account_name ,c.account_users ,a.account_code  
FROM campaign c  
INNER JOIN account a  
GROUP BY c.account_id, c.campaign_id, c.account_name, c.account_users, a.account_code
  HAVING count(*) >= 2;
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, a.account_code FROM campaign c
JOIN account a ON c.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE c.account_id IN (
  SELECT account_id FROM campaign
  GROUP BY account_id
  HAVING count(*) >= 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using COUNT as aggregate function. Try using it as analytical function.

```
select account_id ,campaign_id ,account_name ,account_users ,account_code,
from
   (SELECT c.account_id ,c.campaign_id ,c.account_name ,c.account_users ,a.account_code,
   count(1) over (partition by c.account_id) as c
   FROM campaign c
   INNER JOIN account a on c.account_id = a.account_id)
where c >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `GROUP BY` statement:

`GROUP BY c.account_id, c.campaign_id, c.account_name, c.account_users,`

make it work not as your expect. You should `GROUP BY` **account_id** only since you need **account_id** occurs two or more times on table **campaign**

Something like

```
SELECT c.account_id ,c.campaign_id ,c.account_name ,c.account_users ,a.account_code
FROM campaign c
INNER JOIN account a
where c.account_id in (select account_id
            FROM campaign
            GROUP BY account_id
            HAVING COUNT(account_id) >= 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more to discuss about your table structure, but since you ask a specific question, a short answer would be to replace

```
INNER JOIN account a
```

with

```
INNER JOIN (select distinct account_id,account_code from account) a 
  on (a.account_id=c.account_id)
```

(also, consider adding `COUNT(*)` to your select list, if only for sanity check)

Comment: This should have gotten an upvote. Just the first sentence worths it :) Here is mine

Answer (score 0):

try this query i think that it is what you want:

```
select q.* from
  (select t3.*,count(t3.account_id) as counter,t4.account_code
  from Campaign t3,Account t4
  where t3.id = t4.id
  group by 
  t3.account_id,t3.campaign_id,t3.account_name,t3.account_users,t4.account_code) q
where q.counter>1;
```